# Rename file in other folder with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have this file here

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\folder\folder2\file.exe
```

and I want to rename it to `file2.exe` with this batch file

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\folder\test.bat
```

but I don't now the code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include what you tried so far and what it did and did not do.

Comment: Thank you sir but i'm beginner and I did not try something

Comment: Then your question is, sorry to say, in the wrong place. Beginners are perfectly welcome, but we do expect to see you having tried something and tried to do your research, using standard search engines. Please look around a little bit what kind of questions and answers we usually have.

Comment: Ok i'm sorry next time i will try something first

Answer (score 1):

```
ren "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\folder\folder2\file.exe" "file2.txt"
```

Comment: thanks foxidrive it works perfectly but I need code works in any folder on any computer is this possible?

Comment: You have to say exactly what you want.  "any folder" is not specific to a task.

Comment: You did not understand me well, I want a code that can be used in any folder, and I do not know the names of folders,

Comment: `ren "file.txt" "file2.txt"` <--- this will work in any folder.

Comment: I have this file here 

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\folder\folder2\file.exe

 and I want to rename it to file2.exe with this batch file

 C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\folder\test.bat 

But i can send the folder to a friend , so the code  you gave me 

(ren "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\folder\folder2\file.exe" "file2.txt") 

will not work in his computer Because folders have other names I do
 not know

Comment: May `%userprofile%` help?

Answer (score 0):

From comments, it seems you need

```
ren "%~dp0\folder2\file.exe" "file2.txt"
```

Where `%~dp0` is the drive (`d`) and path (`p`) of the current batch file (`%~0`)